# How to intercept the event "Open link in new tab" on right-click to the link

Tags: angularjs

```
 <a href="" ng-click="viewArticle($index +(currentPage*pageSize))">
    <img ng-src="{{suggestion.imageUrl}}" class="widget-cse__content__item-title-img"/>

    <div class="widget-cse__content__item-title">{{suggestion.title}}</div>
 </a>
```

I have this code above. On click event, the viewArticle method is called where a click counter is incremented. Since href is not used here, it has an empty value. However, I don't know how to handle when the user right clicks on the link and selects "Open link in new tab".

Comment: You want right-click to trigger viewArticle or you want it to show context menu (which contains "open link in new tab")?

Comment: I want the right-click's "open link in new tab" to behave like ng-click. Thx.

Comment: Any luck with this one?

Answer (score 0):

**The jQuery Way**

```
$('a').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    window.location = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

**The AngularJs Way (Pseudo Code)**

Add an attribute that disables the open in new tab, and set the `$location.path` manually

```
element.click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $location.path = attrs.get('href');
});
```

Comment: I am doing this already. It's the contextMenu's "open link in new tab" in Chrome (have not tested with other browsers) that I would like to handle the same way. My code for viewArticle:

    $scope.viewArticle = function (index) {
                         suggestionService.postView($scope.suggestions[index].assetId).then(function (results) {
                        $log.info(results);
                        $scope.suggestions[index].counters.views = results.viewCount;
                    });
                    $window.open($scope.suggestions[index].url);
                }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to generate your `href` on click event then you should use  `ng-mousedown` event so that you can perform any event like `open link in new tab`, `open link in new window` and `click`.

**HTML:**

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" ng-mousedown="viewArticle($event, data)">{{label}}</a>
```

**JS :**

```
  $scope.viewArticle = function (event, data) {

         // Do your work here
         .......

         // After that set href
         jQuery(event.target).attr('href', 'view/article');


  };
```